# Java groupingBy and transform Strings

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I am receiving a List of Strings that I am attempting to partition with `.groupingBy()`, which will give me a `Map<String, List<String>>`, and transform the Strings that are going to end up in the Lists that are in the Map.

[Examples I've found](https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector#10-mapping-grouped-results-to-a-different-type) use `Collectors.mapping` which was what I thought to use, but all of the examples are using a method reference, like `.mapping(SomeClass::getSomething, ...` which, since I'm acting on Strings, can't be done.

I thought I could use a lambda as the mapping function but can't seem to get the syntax right, ending up with "Type mismatch: cannot convert..." errors.

This illustrates the *kind of thing* I'm trying to do —

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
        List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("D8", "S1", "S5", "D2", "D15", "S9");
        System.out.println(inputs);

        Map<String, List<String>>
        outputs = inputs.stream()
              .collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.startsWith("D") ? "desperate" : "serious")
                  //,Collectors.mapping(n -> Integer.valueOf(n.replaceAll("[DS]", "")), Collectors.toList())
              )
              ;

        System.out.println(outputs);
  }
}
```

This creates the Map, grouping the input data as I expect, and produces the output
`{desperate=[D8, D2, D15], serious=[S1, S5, S9]}`

but what I want, as you may guess from the commented out line
`Collectors.mapping(n -> Integer.valueOf(n.replaceAll("[DS]", "")), Collectors.toList())`
is a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` containing the values extracted from the strings by removing the prefix.

My real use cases may transform one String to another String, or extract Integers from a more complex string, but this illustrates what I'm trying to do.

How can I use a lambda function to do the mapping when I'm groupingBy?
I'm also not clear on the use of the second argument `toList()` in `Collectors.mapping` from the examples I've read.

I have created a [repl](https://repl.it/@stephen61/GroupAndTransform) with this code.

Comment: Nothing wrong, just add the extra ')'.

Comment: I think this is just a typo. The `mapping` collector should be the second argument of the `groupingBy` call, not the `collect` call.

Comment: @Sweeper - not sure I'd call that a typo, that I was mis-understanding the collector associations. Figured it out based on Erik's answer.

Comment: I see. Close vote retracted.

Comment: @StephenP, in real world, it would be better to apply the transformations before grouping and then group the transformations. In a practical big data sense, this will have a bigger impact in terms of parallelism. Erik's answer is good. I have added my version too. Transform and group can improve the shuffle and reduce cross node data data transfer (even in a JVM context with parallel streams there might benefits in future). My comment is more about the model rather than the actual code

Comment: @Horse apparently, you have a wrong idea of how streams and collectors work. Whether you apply the mapping in the collector or in a step before the collect, makes no difference at all. You may play around with [this program](https://ideone.com/UhlMKn) (gets better when you copy and run it on a system with more cores and a larger console). You’ll see, in either case, a worker thread will perform the same steps for a particular element and result parallelism is the same.

Comment: @Holger, Thank you for the feedback. My suggestion as mentioned in the previous comment `My comment is more about the model rather than the actual code`. In the Big Data world(say MapReduce), generally its advised to perform the necessary data transformations in a Mapper and then grouping will result in much better performance rather than doing transformations within groupby to arrive at the groupby key. Again, an efficient system should be able to localize this and shuffle only the necessary data. Sorry for mixing the terminologies and Java to other frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collectors.groupingBy()` has a version that takes another collector for the values, for example:

```
@Test
public void streamsTest() {
    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("D8", "S1", "S5", "D2", "D15", "S9");
    System.out.println(inputs);

    Map<String, List<Integer>> outputs = inputs.stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            s -> s.startsWith("D") ? "desperate" : "serious",
                            Collectors.mapping(
                                    s -> Integer.valueOf(s.substring(1)),
                                    Collectors.toList())));

    System.out.println(outputs);
}
```

This produces:

```
[D8, S1, S5, D2, D15, S9]
{desperate=[8, 2, 15], serious=[1, 5, 9]}
```

Comment: Since this is a boolean grouping, it might be more efficient to do `Map<String, List<Integer>> outputs = inputs.stream() .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.partitioningBy(s -> s.startsWith("D"), Collectors.mapping(s -> Integer.valueOf(s.substring(1)), Collectors.toList())), m -> Map.of("desperate", m.get(true), "serious", m.get(false))));` for larger lists. Also, since Java 9, we can parse substrings without creating the string, i.e. `Integer.parseInt(s, 1, s.length(), 10)`. But for simple cases as the question’s example, this doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to [Erik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165200/java-groupingby-and-transform-strings/66165361#66165361). The difference is, transformation can happen outside grouping and can evolve independently.

### Stream, map, group

1. Stream the elements
2. transform each element using the `map` (this can be delegated to a separate function)
3. define collection strategy
4. group based on collection strategy
5. collect the elements per the need

```java
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class TransformAndGroupBy {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> inputs = Arrays.asList("D8", "S1", "S5", "D2", "D15", "S9");

    System.out.println(inputs);

    Function<String, SimpleEntry<String, Integer>> transform = s -> s.startsWith("D")
      ? new SimpleEntry<>("desparate", Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1)))
      : new SimpleEntry<>("serious", Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1)));

    Map<String, List<Integer>> outputs = inputs.stream() // convert to stream
      .map(transform) // do the necessary transformation
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getKey(), Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), Collectors.toList()))); // group and collect as per the transformation
    System.out.println(outputs);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, and my `transform` could be reusable and defined elsewhere, or even be a parameter(?). As I mentioned for "real use cases" I will have different transformations for different sets of (different patterns of) strings.

Comment: @StephenP, You are absolutely correct. You can define as parameter or external function. The output of `map`(transform) types should be available(known) to `collect` to change collection strategy (which in turn can change the result type also). The primary advantage is `map/tranform` is a independent operation and hence can be done in place of data while `group` shuffles can be created based on the group key obtained from transformation. But, if functions are defined inside group, then either all the data has to be in single node or multi level shuffle and reduce are needed.

Comment: Basically, your transformation is a `Function` within an input type and output type. The `groupby` will act on this output type. For a simple program this might be redundant but in large pipelines this arch can help.

Comment: Of course, the code duplication is not necessary. You can also use `Function<String, SimpleEntry<String, Integer>> transform = s -> new SimpleEntry<>(s.startsWith("D")? "desperate": "serious", Integer.parseInt(s.substring(1)));`